# how to archive emails through python in a selected Gmail Mailbox

Tags: python, gmail-imap

i am looking for a way to `archive` selected emails on my gmail mailbox using Python. Any suggestions on how i can achieve this?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you mean by "archive"?

Answer (score 1):

Best tool out there in python is [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) (as I know of), check it out. Perhaps it will solve your problems. It works like fetchmail. If you by `archive` means downloadin to your own machine for storage. If you by `archive` means archiving in gmail, then I don't know.